# How to handle big data in training neural network?

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to do a simple text classification. I've tried different packages, but all of them do the stuff in memory.

It works pretty smoothly for small inputs, but the bigger the input is, the slower is becomes.

```
"use strict";

const NaturalSynaptic = require("natural-synaptic");    

// After getting the data
rows = rows.map(c => (c.content && c.category_name ? {
    input: c.content
  , output: c.category_name
} : null)).filter(Boolean);

var classifier = new NaturalSynaptic();

// This part is relatively fast
rows.forEach((c, i) => {
    classifier.addDocument(c.input, c.output);
});

// It gets stuck here    
classifier.train();
```

After training, I'd like to predict the outputs using the `classifier.classify('did the tests pass?')`.

When it gets stuck, one of the CPUs is jumps to 100%. I suspect it's because of the `for` loops from the library.

What's the right way to do this? How to handle so much data as input?

An after waiting enough time, I ended with this, like I expected:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

 1300704 ms: Mark-sweep 1194.3 (1458.1) -> 1194.3 (1458.1) MB, 238.2 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [scavenge might not succeed].
 1300955 ms: Mark-sweep 1194.3 (1458.1) -> 1194.3 (1458.1) MB, 251.7 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [scavenge might not succeed].
 1301199 ms: Mark-sweep 1194.3 (1458.1) -> 1194.3 (1458.1) MB, 244.0 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
 1301432 ms: Mark-sweep 1194.3 (1458.1) -> 1194.3 (1458.1) MB, 232.9 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1326850e3ac1 <JS Object>
    2: textToFeatures [/home/ionicabizau/.../node_modules/natural/lib/natural/classifiers/classifier.js:~82] [pc=0x3204073474c8] (this=0xd98447d4ab1 <JS Object>,observation=0x2eb16ebfc7d9 <JS Array[36]>)
    3: train [/home/ionicabizau/.../node_modules/natural/lib/natural/classifiers/classifier.js:101] [pc=0x32040734600d]...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Some general remarks: (0) Looks like a memory problem. First check what kind of -> NN taking too much memory vs. Data takes too much (more probable). Decreasing batch-size helps but there is a limit  (1) JS is not the best base for heavy NN learning. (2) Without any knowledge about your lib: grab the basics of NN-training, mostly the basics of Stochastic Gradient Descent. Check your library how to prepare the batches yourself and do that online. So instead of loading 100M samples into the memory, you load for example a 1M block, shuffle, create batches and train each.

Comment: Of course there are some caveats as SGD wants shuffled samples. Maybe there is some literature on this but when you understand the core-concepts and you got information about your environment (all samples, memory, NN-size, batch-size) you could implement some streaming/online-approach like this which is near stochastically-perfect shuffling. E.g. split N into 100 blocks, chose randomly 10, shuffle, prepare batches and learn. Chose next (without replacement). Of course there are tradeoffs in regards to theory/practice (e.g. 10000 blocks call for messy IO-performance)

Comment: This specific library (I'm the creator) was meant as a POC more than anything. It loads up everything into memory and isn't very efficient when it comes to training the model.